# How can I refer to today/the past when talking in future perspective?

Tags: grammar, tenses

In particular, I am confused as to which of these two sentence is correct:

1. Your grandchildren will ask how 2020 **is** like
2. Your grandchildren will ask how 2020 **was** like

The sentence is spoken now (2020), but from the future, 2020 is the past.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

The question the grandchildren will ask is:

- "What *was* 2020 like?"

You should retain the past tense in your statement. So it should be:

- Your grandchildren will ask what 2020 was like.

Note that the usual expression is *What is x like?*, not *How is x like?*

Comment: So we should consider the question that will be asked? Thank you! And thank you for the correction!

Comment: @Yohanes Theda. Yes. Your sentence is an example of indirect speech. Direct speech: _Your grandchildren will ask, "What was 2020 like?"_. Indirect speech: _Your grandchildren will ask what 2020 was like._